# Converting Meter to feet and inches in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have a input field for the user to enter a person's height in meters. But I need to display this as x ft. xx inches. For example they enter in 1.6266 meter, I need to display 5 ft 4 inches.

Can anyone give me an  example of how I would do this?

```
   Single fFeet = Single.Parse(Feet.Text);
   Single fInches = Single.Parse(Inches.Text);
   Double fMeters = 0.305*fFeet + 0.0254*fInches;
  lblMeters.Text = "<b>You are " + fMeters.ToString() + " meters tall</b>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're declaring `fFeet` and `fInches` as Singles I guess you want to round it to the closest inch. If not, correct me on a comment.

```
Double fMeters = Double.Parse(Meters.Text);
Single fFeet = round(fMeters % 0.305,0);
Single fInches = round((fMeters - fFeet*0.305) / 0.0254,0);
```